# Tagging comments in Jira with a label

Tags: tags, blogs, jira

Is there a way to tag comments in Jira and then filter them by these tags, similar to Blog posts functionality in Confluence?
I.e., a group of issues is tagged group1, and if a comment in an unrelated task may affect this group of issues, I just tag it with "group1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you described is usually done with components- tag each issue with it's components, than search issues by:

```
component = group1
```

If you want to keep the labels within the comments, you can define a label, for example use `<<label>>`, and add it to your comments. Than, search for issues:

```
comment ~ "\"<<group1>>\""
```

you can also use one of Jira's markups, such as `[#anchor]`.

For more information check [Performing Text Searches](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Performing+Text+Searches) and [Advanced Searching](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching)

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question asked how to attribute a comment. Your answer describes how to attribute an issue. Maybe you just wanted to answer: No way?